# Convert code from python to java or c# or pseudocode

Tags: python

Maybe someone could help and convert this code from python to c# or java? :/ Or knows where I could find online converter.

```
def findWay(N):
    S = [1,3,4] 
    partial_sums = [ [[k], k] for k in S if k <= N ] 
    total_sums = [ [k] for k in S if k == N ] 
    for _ in range(N): 
        new_sums = []
        for (l, sum) in partial_sums:
            for k in S:
                if sum+k < N:
                    new_sums.append([l+[k], sum+k])
                elif sum+k == N:
                    total_sums.append(l+[k])
        partial_sums = new_sums
    return total_sums
```

Comment: I think you need to learn about [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in Python.

Comment: and [tuples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tuples-in-python/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a code **transpiler** ( converting one type of code into another).

- For Python to C or FORTRAN you can use [transpyle](https://pypi.org/project/transpyle/)
- For the Python to Java you may look at [VOC](https://voc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)